# The difference between Number as an object and Number as a constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, wrapper, theory

When we try to print `Number` on the screen ex: `document.querySelector('#test').textContent = Number` we get the result : `function Number() { [native code] }`. so this is the definition of a constructor method. but then how come that the same name is used for the object number wrapper `Number` which has couple of methods and fields (properties) such as `Number.MAX_VALUE`? .., i.e what is the difference between the two?

Comment: They're the same thing. It's a constructor and has static properties not on the prototype. A function is an object too.

Comment: Could you give an example of piece of code.., thx in advance.

Comment: "*so this is the definition of a constructor method.*" - How do you judge that from the string representation? All I see is a `function`, not a constructor or method.

Comment: ^^! there is a convention for naming constructors.., where the first letter is capital.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one `Number` object. To understand why, you have to remember how JavaScript works... Look at this basic example:

```js
function Test(foo, bar) {
  this.foo = foo;
  this.bar = bar;
  
  return "Hello!";
}

Test.bye = function () {
  return "Bye!";
};

console.log(new Test('Foo', 'Bar'));
console.log(Test('Foo', 'Bar'));
console.log(Test.bye());
```

Comment: ^^ definitely.., I'm actually reviewing the subject. and you refreshed my memory.., thx again.

Comment: Cool! Have a great time with JavaScript... ;)

Answer (score 1):

First you have to understand how to work with class and objects in javascript.

Although javascript is not object-oriented, it simulates some of OOP principles.

You can simulate a class like below:

```
//class/constructor definition
function MyCustomType() {}

//static property
MyCustomType.SOME_CONSTANT_VALUE = "Hello, ";

//property of class
MyCustomType.prototype.Name = "World";

//methods
MyCustomType.prototype.getName = function () {
    return MyCustomType.SOME_CONSTANT_VALUE + this.Name;
}
```

Is important understand some elements like prototype and why your use is better then use

> this

on constructor.

So, to give you a more specific response, the native Number is like a class that have some static properties.

Comment: Thank you. I come from Java programming background. Nevertheless, that was helpful. I guess you forgot to put () in >>   function MyCustomType() {}

Comment: @ProfessPhysics Corrected!